# How do I get file contents from github apiv4 on the default branch?

Tags: graphql, github-api

I've had a lot of success pulling README.md content from the github v4 syntax found in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248607/how-to-get-readme-md-from-github-graphql-api/46254836) as follows:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "gitpoint", name: "git-point") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      name
    }
    object(expression: "master:README.md") {
      ... on Blob {
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My issue comes when defaultBranchRef.name is not `master`.  We can expect this to be the case more frequently moving forward as people move away from that naming convention for various reasons.

How do I change the expression to reference the repo's default branch name if I don't know it till I query?  Or must I make 2 queries per repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HEAD:[path]` as expression to get the default branch :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "gitpoint", name: "git-point") {
    object(expression: "HEAD:README.md") {
      ... on Blob {
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```